# How to use dependabot secrets in GitHub CI workflow

Tags: github, npm, continuous-integration, dependabot

I have a `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` secret which was originally stored in my actions secrets which doesn't seem to be accessible by dependabot when it automatically opens a PR.

I have now copied this secret into Dependabot Secrets. Do I need to change anything in my CI so that it can access it?

```yaml
- name: Authenticate with Github Package Registry
  run:
    npm config set '//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken' "${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}"
  env:
    NPM_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

The above action is run by both PR's opened by developers as well as dependabot. Will `secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` be the value from Actions Secrets when opened by a developer and then be the value from Dependabot Secrets when opened by Dependabot?

Answer (score 4):

github secrets are managed separately between actions, codespaces, and dependabot. You will need to set the same `NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` for dependabot, and then you can use it for both regular action run and the dependabot PRs.

You can check the secrets that dependabot can see by running `gh secret list --app dependabot` inside repo.